# Springboot : Circular Dependecy issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, java-17

I Migrated from SpringBoot2.7.2 to Springboot3.1.5 and my code started failing with the following error

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

    webSecurityConfig
          ↓
       securityService
          ↓
       userRepository defined in com.ner.usermgmt.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration
          ↓
       jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory
    ┌─────┐
    |  liquibase defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]
```

In My SecurityService.java class i modified like this

```
    //@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //@Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

   // @Autowired
    private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

    @Autowired
    private LocaleService localeService;

    @Autowired
    private EncodingService encodingService;

   // @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    //@Autowired
    private SystemParameterService systemParameterService;

    //@Autowired
    private UserPasswordRepository userPasswordRepository;

   @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthorizationService(AuthorizationService authorizationService) {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setSystemParameterService(SystemParameterService systemParameterService) {
        this.systemParameterService = systemParameterService;
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setUserPasswordRepository(UserPasswordRepository userPasswordRepository) {
        this.userPasswordRepository = userPasswordRepository;
    }
```

And in user Repository its simple code

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Long> {
    

    @Query(value = "Some Query" )", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> fetchLoginDevUsernames();

}
```

But still code is telling ,my code-base have Circular Dependency . Can Someone guide here what is wrong with my understanding.

Even in my application.properties i added

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
```

More log

> [36mo.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter   Error starting Tomcat
> context. Exception:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
> Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityService'
> parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'securityService':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUserRepository'
> parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in
> com.ner.usermgmt.repository.UserRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while
> setting bean property 'entityManager'

[image]

Edit

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Value("${db.schema:}")
    private String dbSchema;
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization
    public CustomSpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(dbSchema)) {
            liquibase.setDefaultSchema(dbSchema);
        } else {
            liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
        }
        liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
        liquibase.setLabels(properties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties.getParameters());
        liquibase.setRollbackFile(properties.getRollbackFile());
        return new CustomSpringLiquibase(liquibase);
    }
```

**Existing code**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Value("${db.schema:}")
    private String dbSchema;
    
    
    @Bean
    @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization
    SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties properties) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setChangeLog(properties.getChangeLog());
        liquibase.setContexts(properties.getContexts());
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(dbSchema)) {
            liquibase.setDefaultSchema(dbSchema);
        } else {
            liquibase.setDefaultSchema(properties.getDefaultSchema());
        }
        liquibase.setDropFirst(properties.isDropFirst());
        liquibase.setShouldRun(properties.isEnabled());
        liquibase.setLabels(properties.getLabels());
        liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(properties.getParameters());
        liquibase.setRollbackFile(properties.getRollbackFile());
        return liquibase;
    }
```

Comment: There is a part missing in your cycle as this appears to be cut off. Please include the full logging.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you mean Application Failed to Start ? If yes i added.

Comment: No after liquibase, or your formatting got screwed up, but currently we cannot see what forms a cycle.

Comment: @M.Deinum After that this one `Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

`

Comment: add @Lazy annotation.

Comment: @AnotherOne I added that in `securityService` and `UserService`   .But no any help.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't clear as what Spring Boot thinks forms a circular dependency, this is propably due to some formatting issue, but without knowing how the circulair dependency is made it will be impossible to answer. As a last resort you could post a screenshot of your logging with the proper formatting.

Comment: @M.Deinum Added Screenshot.

Comment: Now that is weird. Liquibase depends on Liquibase... But that is due to your `LiquibaseConfig`. What is there so custom about your init that you need this instead of the regular setup? You could try and exclude the auto confguration for Liquibase in the `@SpringBootAPplication` as apparently you don't use it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thats a Existing code, i added a CustomSpringLiquibase to overcome Cyclic Dependency issue.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Is this existing code or did you add it to fix something? As your comment feels contradicting both statements!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256034/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-m-deinum).